# How can I model association between two polymorphic classes without using an enumeration

Tags: c#, oop, enums, polymorphism, model-associations

I am using an `enum` to label two different classes of products - a SensorDevice and a [data]CaptureDevice.
They are intended to be used physically plugged to one another, but not every sensor model can be used by each receiver model, so I created an Enum for the different platforms, so the GUI would only display the compatible accessories for a given device:

```cs
enum Platform {
    Standard,
    Deluxe,
    Jumbo
}

abstract class CaptureDevice
{
    public Platform platform;

    public bool IsCompatibleWith(SensorDevice sd)
    {
        return sd.Platforms.Contains(this.Platform); // <- this is type-checking!
    }
}

abstract class SensorDevice
{
    public IEnumerable<Platform> Platforms;

    public bool IsCompatibleWith(CaptureDevice cd)
    {
        return this.Platforms.Contains(cd.Platform); // <- this is type-checking!
    }
}
```

I started to find this quite smelly, since the enum is hard-coded. I am considering to use "Replace Type Code by Polymorphism" refactor, but I am not quite sure how to do it for this situation. Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you chose which `Platform` for which `Device` ? It is by rule name or totally arbitrary ? Can you show some implemented Devices ?

Comment: Let the platfom ask the sensor if it's comaptible. This will allow you to Hide the Platforms Enumeration on the sensor, Then refactor Sensors as needed to remove use of platform enum there.  However this may be more work as there is a use.

Comment: @romain-aga the rule is arbitrary. In theory, it would have to do with geometrical and electrical characteristics of the sensor, but are also commercial and portfolio considerations. So yes, it is arbitrary. Also, there is no certainty at all that in the future other platform models won't be available, with the undesireable need to "recompile" the enum.

Comment: @ReneA If I understand right, this is currently what happens when you call `aCaptureDevice.IsCompatibleWith(aSensorDevice)`. What I am looking for is a way to implement this signature _without_ using an `enum` at all!

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to get rid of enum.

Replace enum with a class.

```
public abstract class Platform {}
```

Add `Device` class which answers if it's compatible with a `Platform`.

```
public abstract class Device
{
    public abstract bool IsCompatibleWith(Platform platform);
}
```

Make `CaptureDevice` a subclass of `Device`.

```
public abstract class CaptureDevice : Device
{
    public Platform Platform;

    public override bool IsCompatibleWith(Platform platform)
    {
        // I'm using type comparison for the sake of simplicity,
        // but you can implement different business rules in here.

        return this.Platform.GetType() == platform.GetType();
    }

    public bool IsCompatibleWith(SensorDevice sd)
    {
       // We are compatible if sensor is compatible with my platform.

        return sd.IsCompatibleWith(this.Platform);
    }
}
```

Make `SensorDevice` a subclass of `Device`.

```
public abstract class SensorDevice : Device
{
    public IEnumerable<Platform> Platforms;

    public override bool IsCompatibleWith(Platform platform)
    {
        // I'm using type comparison again.

        return this.Platforms.Any(p => p.GetType() == platform.GetType());
    }

    public bool IsCompatibleWith(CaptureDevice cd)
    {
        // We are compatible if capture is compatible with one of my platforms. 

        return this.Platforms.Any(p => cd.IsCompatibleWith(p));
    }
}
```

Basically, that's all you need to do. To illustrate how it works, I've added the code below.

```
// Platforms
public class StandardPlatform : Platform { }
public class DeluxPlatform : Platform { }
public class JumboPlatform : Platform { } 

// Capture device(s)
public class CD1 : CaptureDevice
{
    public CD1()
    {
        Platform = new StandardPlatform();
    }
}

// Sensor device(s)
public class SD1 : SensorDevice
{
    public SD1()
    {
        Platforms = new List<Platform>
        {
            new StandardPlatform(),
            new DeluxPlatform()
        };
    }
}

public class SD2 : SensorDevice
{
    public SD2()
    {
        Platforms = new List<Platform> {new JumboPlatform()};
    }
}

// Somewhere in the code...
var cd1 = new CD1();
var sd1 = new SD1();

Console.WriteLine(cd1.IsCompatibleWith(sd1)); // True
Console.WriteLine(sd1.IsCompatibleWith(cd1)); // True

var sd2 = new SD2();
Console.WriteLine(sd2.IsCompatibleWith(cd1)); // False
Console.WriteLine(cd1.IsCompatibleWith(sd2)); // False
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If you want to get rid off the enum, why shouldn't use a config file ?

You configure your platforms like this:

```
<Platforms>
    <Platform name="Standard">
        <Device>Namespace.of.your.Device.CaptureDevice</Device>
        <Device>Namespace.of.another.Device.AnotherDevice</Device>
    </Platform>
    <Platform name="Deluxe">
        <Device>Namespace.of.your.Device.CaptureDevice</Device>
    </Platform>
</Platforms>
```

Other syntax:

```
<Platforms>
    <Platform>
        <Name>Standard</Name>
        <Devices>
            <Device>Namespace.of.your.Device.CaptureDevice</Device>
            <Device>Namespace.of.another.Device.AnotherDevice</Device>
        <Devices>
    </Platform>
</Platforms>
```

Then, you have the same base structure, you could do something like this:

```
abstract class ADevice<T> where T : ADevice<T>
{
    public ADevice<T>(T device , string filename)
    {
        // Parsing of the file
        // Plus, setting the Platforms Property
    }

    // Or (but you should keep the first constructor to see the filename dependency)
    public ADevice<T>(T device)
    {
        // Parsing of the file
    }

    public IEnumerable<Platform> Platforms { get; private set; }

    public bool IsCompatibleWith(T device)
    {
        return this.Platforms.Contains(device.Platform); // <- this is type-checking!
    }
}
```

Then:

```
abstract class CaptureDevice : ADevice<CaptureDevice>
{
    public CaptureDevice(CaptureDevice device, string filename)
        : base(device, filename)
    {
    }

    // Or (But still same comment)
    public CaptureDevice(CaptureDevice device)
        : base(device, defaultFilename)
    {
    }
}
```

*Same for `SensorDevice`*

And instead of the `Enum`, you can create a simple class for the moment as:

```
public class Platform
{
    public Platform(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Comment: @heltonbiker, I edited my post, if you are still looking for a solution about this enum. That might interest you.